# Report Items on top of each other are repositioning

Tags: reporting-services

How do you stop controls purposely placed on top of each other from re-positioning when in preview mode on a tablix cell.
I created my first control by selecting the cell (right clicked and chose the insert menu - selected a linear gauge chart.
My second control (Textbox - background = No Color) I created first in the body then dragged on top on the gauge however, the Textbox replaces the gauge. I then tried a inserting a rectangle first then placed my 2 controls in the rectangle on top of each other and resize everything however when I preview the textbox is placed above the gauge and thus the column height expands to the height of the textbox + gauge. I read somewhere else the trick is to put the gauge behind the rectangle i.e. its parent is the cell but how do you do that? The z-order is grayed-out (disabled) and clicking the toolbar button "send to back" does nothing I assume this only works within the context of its container (i.e. the rectangle, not the cell) and if you place the gauge first it fills the entire cell then placing the rectangle on top replaces the gauge same scenario as before with the textbox.

My first option was actually to add a Label to the gauge however, I could not figure out how to allow me to place the label to sit on top of the gauge and have the font size fixed, I believe labels are used for marking gauge lines as supposed to simply a label used as a comment.

The result I want to achieve is my cell has a value field that I want to bind to the text field and I also want to bind the gauge value to the percentage of the sum of all values. So say I have 3 rows with scores of 10, 30, 10, then the respective gauge values will be (10/50 * 100) = 20, 60, 20 respectively. The problem not so much the mathematics but how to achieve the display.

Design:

[image]

Preview:

[image]

The effect I want is the 71 (textbox) should be on top of the gauge control and row should not expand to 2 rows.

Comment: Screenshot would help to understand your problem better

Comment: Screen shot added for emphasis

Comment: Have you tried to use Label on Gauge for this? I do not thing you can control overlapping in SSRS on all renderers (mostly not)

Comment: Yes I tried a label however the label sits under the gauge (Linear Gauge Pointer) so even if the value is right justified a large gauge value will partially hide it and besides it gave some runtime error when I previewed which I did not bothered looking into I suspect as I said in description above that a label has to be binded somehow to the ticks.